# Put Data into a dynamic array in VBA and split string into key value pairs

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-arrays

I have some raw data below which I am trying to format in Excel Spreadsheet.

The Data is formated as below

[image: The Data is formated as below]

I need to format this data in VBA to where it looks like this.

[image: I need the data to look like this.]

The last row, "CTP Parameters", needs to be separated into key value pairs while the other information stays the same until the part number changes. This some of the code that I have in VBA. I know I need to put this information into a dynamic array. I am new to VBA though.

```
Sub SplitKeyPairs()
    'Variables
    Dim myString As String
    Dim kpArr() As String
    Dim i, j As Integer

    i = 2
    j = 2
    
    Do
        myString = Range("F" & i)
    

        'Split the string based on the line break
        For Each keypair In Split(myString, "~")
            'Split the keypair value
            kpArr = Split(keypair, "^")
        
            'Copy keys on B column and values on C column
            Range("G" & j) = kpArr(0)
            Range("H" & j) = Replace(kpArr(1), "~", "")

            j = j + 1

        Next

        i = i + 1
    Loop While Range("F" & i) <> ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you're doing but since you're using the word keys, maybe try `dictionary`?

Comment: So, it's a bit difficult to see, even maximizing and scrolling into the first image, but it appears that you're splitting a string... however, with how you're choosing the order, and what other options may appear, this could be problematic.  Imagine `array = Split(cells(1,1).value)," ")`, where `cells(1,1).value = "this long string of text"`:  How do I tell VBA what I'm searching for, and the order to put it in?  Additionally, if I loop to the next cell and it's "this extraneously long string of sullen text", how will I know what to extract for my use?

Comment: I suggest you create a proper sample that others can use to help you troubleshoot your code. A screen shot of data is not very useful as it cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet.  Please edit your question to post that data as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.